# Self-attention in Transformers, are the component values of input vector trained or is it the set W_q, W_k, W_v?

Tags: transformer, attention-mechanism

By far, I find this tutorial on self-attention the most digestible (https://peterbloem.nl/blog/transformers)

Still, I got a question from reading there, hopefully, you guys can help me out

- Are the component values of the input vectors updated throughout the training? (or the learned parts are the weight matrix Wq, Wk, Wv)?

In the blog, the first part said:

***Since we are learning what the values in t should be, how "related" two words are is entirely determined by the task. In most cases, the definite article the is not very relevant to the interpretation of the other words in the sentence; therefore, we will likely end up with an embedding the that have a low or negative dot product with all other words***

So I assume the components of v_the will be learned. Say, if it has 4 component values, like 
v_the = [ 1, 2, 3, 4], then after certain epochs of training, it will become like v_the = [0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001]

But then a bit further down,  when he started introducing W_q, W_k, and W_v, he said:

***This gives the self-attention layer some controllable parameters and allows it to modify the incoming vectors to suit the three roles they must play.***

So now it seems like we just keep the starting values of the input vectors in tact, and the training process will just update the corresponding W_q, W_k, W_v

Hence the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The training of a self-attention layer will result in the update of the $W$ matrices and the gradient being propagated back to the previous layer.

At the end of the self-attention blocks, the back-propagated gradient will arrive to the embedded vectors, which will also be updated.

As personal advice, I would suggest that you don't try to understand *why* self-attention works, just how it works. The analogies made in the linked post about the embeddings of "the", "cat" and "walk" are nonsense in my opinion. First, nowadays most neural text processing models work at the subword level, not at the word level. Also, self-attention layers are stacked, so the token identities are lost after the first layer (unless you are training something like a masked language model where you predict the very same input tokens at the same positions).
*

Comment: Thanks @noe, I understand the subword part you mention, like BPE or WordPiece, but before your answer, I was wondering the value of the incoming vectors (before entering self-attention layer) are trained (updated) or not. Now it's clearer, they are not, are they?

Comment: It depends on where those incoming vectors come from. In the first self-attention layer, they come from the embeddings; in that case, they are updated. In the other self-attention layers, they come from the outputs of previous self-attention blocks, so the gradients are propagated backward.

Comment: Hi @noe, tks for your comment. So I misunderstood the author. OK, so the next question: if the weight matrices W_Q, W_K, W_V are trained, then theoretically we just keep the weight of input embeddings the same (randomly initiated values), then why the need to train them (them = input embeddings)?

Comment: The embeddings are trained, they are not kept the same

Comment: Thanks @noe, I just ask that for theoretical clarity: if ... then  theoretically... (above comment), there's no need to train input embeddings, is it true?

Comment: Then it seems that you are asking: "If embeddings are not trained then why do we need to train them?". I am sure I am missing something. Please, clarify.

Comment: First, in theory, if we don't train input embeddings, we would achieve the same effects by training only the W_x matrices, right? 

If that is right, then next is the question: why do we need to train them?

Comment: No, if we don't train the input embeddings we won't achieve the same effect. That's a wrong assumption.

Comment: Thanks @noe for clarifying!

Comment: Please, consider accepting the answer if you consider it correct. Alternatively, please indicate why you consider it is not, or what is not clear from it.

Comment: Done, thanks for your help

Comment: Here is just a picky (not really useful) comment. You said "token identities are lost after the first layer" but what about the residual connexions? Seeing that operations are just sum and norm in the residual stream I feel like the token identity is not lost, there is just other stuff around it.

Comment: What I meant is that the information from all tokens is mixed together at every token position. So, not necessarily lost, but the information at that position is no longer only about the token at that position.